# measure equality on two sigma algebras also holds on the combined sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

we have the following setup:

$Q, P \text{ are measures on the }\sigma-\text{algebras } \mathcal{F} \text{ and } \mathcal{G} $. Let $P(A)=Q(A) \forall A\in\mathcal{F}$ and $P(B)=Q(B) \forall B\in\mathcal{G}$. Does then also that $P=Q$ on $\mathcal{F}\lor\mathcal{G}$?
Actually that looks not too hard and my guess is that there is either a nice theorem which says there is some nice way to generate the algebras with pairwise disjoint elements (maybe only in a special case) or an easy counterexample for that, but right now I have no concrete idea.

We know that $\mathcal{F}\cup\mathcal{G}:=\{a\cup b|a\in\mathcal{F},b\in\mathcal{G}\}$ is an EDIT{not intersection}-stable generator of $\mathcal{F}\lor\mathcal{G}$ and therefore it's enough to only look at $a \cap b$. Not even in the discrete $\Omega$-scenario I was able to find a convenient solution. Any ideas and comments are appreciated!

bests

Comment: $\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{G}$ is not stable under intersections, in general.

Comment: Anyway, what do you mean by saying $P=Q$ on $\mathcal{F} \vee \mathcal{G}$?  They are only defined on $\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{G}$, and it's not clear that either one has a countably additive extension to $\mathcal{F} \vee \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Hi, that could already answer my question, in fact I thought if P and Q are defined on $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ then there would be a natural extension to $\mathcal{F}\lor\mathcal{G}$...you say this is not the case?

Comment: Well, what makes you think it *is* true?  I do not know a counterexample to existence of an extension off the top of my head, but uniqueness definitely can fail.  Consider a sample space with two coin flips, $\mathcal{F}$ generated by the first flip and $\mathcal{G}$ by the second.  Defining a measure on $\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{G}$, you can ensure that each coin has probability $1/2$ of coming up heads, but there are infinitely many extensions to $\mathcal{F} \vee \mathcal{G}$, depending on how correlated you want the coins to be.

Comment: So in other words, it's possible to have two measures $P,Q$ on $\mathcal{F} \vee \mathcal{G}$ which agree on $\mathcal{F} \cup \mathcal{G}$ yet are not equal.  Would that resolve your question?

Comment: well, since you you put it like that, actually this shows that I misunderstood something here and I will re-evaluate my question, thank you! (but it seems that my question is resolved)